# Getting a notification when a question that's not yours is answered

Tags: feature-request, answers, notifications, bookmark

Stack Overflow should be enhanced with a "Need Answer" functionality. A user could mark a question that's not his, and then a notification will be generated when a new answer arrives for that question.

Is this type of functionality feasible?

Comment: I know we can add `favourite` question, but this do not keep user informed through inbox notification..

Comment: You have Bounty option to do same.

Comment: @RahulNikate for that you have to provide bounty. But if you are interested to know only different answer then?

Comment: @RahulNikate: You generally do not add bounty to question as normal tendency.. and if you do, it is for single question.. But at same time, you may be interested to know answers of many other good candidate questions.. what about them?

Comment: For bounty option, user need to pay reputation..

Comment: There is an RSS feed you can use.

Comment: How RSS feed works?

Comment: On the bottom right of the page there's an RSS link ("question feed) for every question.

Comment: If stack UI can provide perticular UI on main content area, it will increase visibility.. The RSS Feed are not mostly used by major proportion of users